# What is difference between "active" and " active" in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between the next two codes:

`dots[slideIndex - 1].className += "active";`

And

`dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";`

Comment: `className` property is a string with `css` classes separated by `spaces`, so if you forgot to include the space, you will be **renaming** the last class of that string, not including a new one. Assume `className` is `firstClass secondClass`, then first approach will generate the incorrect `firstClass secondClassactive` while second approach will generate the correct result `firstClass secondClass active`

Comment: You can also use **classList** which might be easier

Answer (score 0):

From here: [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)

> The className property of the Element interface gets and sets the value of the class attribute of the specified element.

and

> className is a string variable representing the class or space-separated classes of the current element.

Then, `className` property is a string with the element's classes separated by spaces. So if you forgot to include the space on your code, you will be renaming the last class of that string, not including a new one.

Assume, for example, that `className` of element `dots[slideIndex - 1]` is equal to `"firstClass secondClass"` before executing your code, then the first approach (`dots[slideIndex - 1].className += "active"`) will generate the incorrect result of `className` equal to:

`"firstClass secondClassactive"`

while the second approach (`dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active"`) will generate the correct result of `className` equal to:

`"firstClass secondClass active"`